# Stick with PHP or learn Go-lang?

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, go

I have learned in my University time `Pascal` and `C` and `RedHat Linux/Unix` .

To get quickly one job, i started learning `Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0` for speed in development etc. In that time, with C its like more time consuming and i was not confident to use it for job purpose, where most of the companies demand fast/rapid development.

After that i had problems with my companies because they want web applications, then i started using PHP which is also great, because customers demand web projects and they expect Google like applications in short time frame, which is doable because PHP gives that speed and its huge community.

To explain my need for Go-lang is following:

- PHP the syntax is friendly compared to C/Pascal.
- I was very happy to learn Python, but its syntax is very much different then C. 
  Which just  not gonna work with me to accept and really learn it better and better.
- I have tried to learn Ruby, at-least so that i can have the knowledge of Python 
  like syntax, but i really skipped Ruby because of 2x time slower then PHP

Therefore,

Is Go-lang is the perfect choice for SPEED vs PHP vs Ruby, for Web development + Gtk?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow -- see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: You should ask this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.  That site is intended to answer this sort of discursive question.  SO deals with questions which are capable of a definitive answer.

Comment: Speed is usually not that much an issue in web development because you can make extensive use of caching etc. Thus, Ruby, PHP or Python are actually very good for web development. What do you mean by "Gtk"?

Comment: I would say stick with PHP and learn some good frameworks (Zend/Symfony--which helps to build good oop skills and rich web development)

You can continue PHP, and focus on some rich web skills (CSS/HTML5/JS-Jquery/Mobile frameworks like Sencha/JQM etc), which are quite popular skills these days.


Go-Lang is not that popular yet. Don't think you can find much resources online when compared to Python/PHP/Ruby etc.

Comment: yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171964/stick-with-php-or-learn-ruby-on-rails is practically the same question and getting lots of responses. Go figure!

Comment: @gbjbaanb: I don't think that question should still be open, as it's equally off-topic.

Comment: @gbj that question is from 2008. It was a different time.

Comment: What he said.  In the early days of SO they allowed questions which now would be closed.  Some of the more egregious examples have been closed and/or deleted, but there are plenty of anomalies still hanging around.

Comment: @simchona: After 2008 it looks like 2012 came. And RoR is very strong community now. Will it be same for Go-lang if you compare 2008?

Comment: YumYum It wasn't a comment on RoR versus GoLang. It was, as @APC picked up on, a comment on the fact that in 2008 questions like that were allowed whereas now they are not.

Comment: `but i really skipped Ruby because of 2x time slower then PHP` - Unless you're writing a webapp used by a LOT (10,000+ concurrent connections) of people, you shouldn't be worrying about this. Say no to premature optimization!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, I'd love to have 1 asset that I could use for all conditions but it's just not available in the world of computing. You're going to have to learn 2 or more.

PHP is very widely used, so you might as well stick with it. If you can create decent webapps using it, go for it. I would suggest learning C/C++ too so you can write any high-performance modules using that and call them from your PHP code. That's probably the best of all worlds for your webapps.

If you wanted to write for desktops, I think you'll be best off learning C++ with Qt (and look at Wt) (as it appears you're a Linux dev), or C#/VB.NET for Windows.

For mobiles, learn C/C++ as you can write apps in that no matter which platform even if you have to put up with some platform-dependant extensions - you either have to learn Java for Android, Objective-C for iOS, or (well we're not quite sure what MS has planned for Windows Phone 8, but I hear they like native code again, that means C++/CX). You can see where I'm going with this!

so anyway, if you're happy with PHP then keep with it. There is a ton of code out there that runs PHP so it's not like you're working with some bleeding-edge or hardly-used obscure language.

Comment: How is PHP+C better than Python+C, Ruby+C, ... for web development?

Comment: @NiklasB: because the OP knows it and doesn't really know Python or Ruby. It wouldn't be valid to recommend a new language to him when the one he has works well enough.

Comment: Okay, although I don't think that learning a new language can hurt (especially because it's hard to know how to code "proper" PHP without ever having laid hands on a more strictly typed language).

Comment: booo detractor, go seems to be great. it's easy and it's fast.

Comment: It's probably much, much faster to learn both Java and Objective C than it is to learn C++. At least if you're interested in learning them well enough to produce something that's even moderately complex.

Anyway, learning Golang is an investment. PHP gets complicated as soon as you try moving to a differently configured server, and its C-style includes poorly facilitate modularity. Golang is generally a better language for web development (and desktop development, for that matter).

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? It reads like a sum-up of the google investigations which the OP most probably already did. No facts, just guessing. It is not answering at all, not even that PHP and Go are (not only) speed-wise extremely different by design. No, do not stick to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is obviously quite subjective, but I find PHP can always be as fast as it needs to be. I spend a lot of time looking up on how my code can be optimised further.

Some good optimisation tips: http://labs.phurix.net/posts/50-php-optimisation-tips-revisited

Of course, in the end, everything depends on what you're willing to do for extra speed and what's practical or not.

Comment: Many of those optimization tips are too much of premature ones, though (don't tell me you see a *visible* increase of speed when using single quotes rather than double), but other tips are really useful (coding standards, using Memchace, etc)

Comment: I use double quotes in most cases, except for identifiers such as array indexes and where I'm interpreting the string as a char sequence. I haven't even read that list yet, it's just something I've found.

Comment: I think most would argue that code cleanness is more important than squeezing out an extra few CPU cycles. Moreover, the major limitation in most web applications is network I/O. The execution speed of a language is relatively unimportant unless you're doing some heavy processing behind the scenes.